# Function to read CSV headers and create an array based on what the column contains

Tags: php

In php - I'm trying to find a way to write a function to read all the headers/first line of a CSV file and create arrays based on what the header is. Sorry this sounds confusing. Basically, when a user uploads a CSV file I want to make sure it will convert into the arrays i've set out. Each CSV could be different, so I want to find a way that will find the '**Description**' column, and move it to a position that matches my 'preset arrays' and then imports each row.

It's hard for me to explain, I'll try to write something down below.

I want the order to be **'Date, Type, Description'**.
Let's say a user uploads a CSV and it has **'Type, Description, Date'**

I want to make a function that reorders them so that if the CSV data is laid out different, then it will re-order it correctly, headers and rows.

Comment: the first call to `fgetcsv()` will give you the first line.

Answer (score 0):

The `key_search` function will return the position of the headers. You can use `array_search` instead. I just  made a function just in case the headers have extra spaces. Feel free to modify it if you want to make the search case insensitive. Just make sure the encoding is utf-8

```
$file = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'r');
$row = fgetcsv($file);

$dateIndex = key_search("Date", $row);
$typeIndex = key_search("Type",$row);
$descIndex = key_search("Description", $row);
$sortedArray = [];

while(($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
    $sortedArray[] = [
        'Date' => $row[$dateIndex], 
        'Type' => $row[$typeIndex], 
        'Description' => $row[$descIndex]
        ];
}

function key_search($field_name, $fields){

    foreach($fields as $key => $value){

        if(trim($value) == $field_name){

            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but i'm not sure how to show the rows under the headers. Let's say row 2 is '01/10/2019, 123, description 1', and row 3 is '02/10/2019, 345, description 2' and so on. How can those be sorted correctly too? thanks, really appreciate this.

Comment: It is sorted while iterating in the `while` loop. In this case into the `$sortedArray`. Each line is indexed with integer keys, so the trick is to get the index of the headers and use them to determine the location of the values for the rest of the rows. @GaryB

Comment: Hmm, I can echo out the key, but there doesn't seem to be any values stored inside. The sortedArray prints out like this [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 
            [Type] => 
            [Description] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 
            [Type] => 
            [Description] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 
            [Type] => 
            [Description] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 
            [Type] => 
            [Description] => 
        )

Comment: Do you get any error @GaryB? Hmm, that's weird. I just tested this, the only difference is my file is in another encoding, so I have it converted first.

Comment: Strange isn't it, I just created a new CSV to test, still blank inside the sortedArray, [Date] => [Type] => [Description] =>, maybe i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Also, how are you printing out the sortedArray? are you looping through it or just printing/var dumping it? thanks again

Comment: I print_r 'ed it. Hope you can find the solution.